# Central Standard Time Off By an Hour

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm having an issue where my time is off by an hour. I'm trying to create a time that has a time zone of CT. In doing so, I have this line of code:

```
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
```

And it's showing this:

> {(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)}

Why? It's 12-Jul-2018 right now, and CT is UTC-05. So why does my debugging info show UTC-06? In the VS debugger, the object also has this:

> SupportsDaylightSavingTime = true

If it matters, I'm in the ET, which is UTC-04 right now.

Comment: Because it's currently "Central Daylight Time", not "Central Standard Time"?

Comment: I thought that as well, but I don't think my system has a time zone of "Central Daylight Time." I don't see it in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\.

Comment: If I change the call to use "Central Daylight Time", I get this: System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: 'The time zone ID 'Central Daylight Time' was not found on the local computer.'

Comment: @SonerGönül I'm in Ohio. I don't think the city should matter.

Comment: I guess the question really is, what are you trying to do with the time zone? Maybe there's a better way of getting what you want.

Comment: Well, that's a whole other issue. We're storing our dates in the DB as UTC. We're displaying them in the UI as CT. I'm in the ET, entering times for a filter to see the data. I'm trying to use the ET date/time (that I entered as a filter) to create a CT datetime, then convert to UTC to match the DB.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#datetime_topic6

Comment: Why not just convert from ET to UTC?

Comment: That doesn't work. The data is displayed in CT, which was converted from UTC in the DB. So, the data may show something like 5:17. In my filter, I'm specifying start and end times, so 5:00 - 6:00, in order to capture the record at 5:17. However, if I convert ET (entered on my machine) to UTC, that gives me a different time than UTC stored in the DB, because it was converted from CT.

Comment: The info is correct, CST is UTC-06:00.  Most web sites insist that it is UTC-05:00 when you browse to them in the summer, they show CDT.  The debugger has no reason to adjust for the daylight savings adjustment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 6 hour offset comes from [`TimeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.baseutcoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which is the difference between UTC and the time zone's **standard time**, not the actual time.

Use [`TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getutcoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the actual offset

```
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
var baseOffset = zone.BaseUtcOffset; // UTC-06:00
var actualOffset = zone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.UtcNow); // UTC-05:00
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem. I was using `BaseUtcOffset`, and `GetUtcOffset()` did it. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the reason its different is because -6 is the default ignoring the current date, and once you give it a DateTime it calculates if it's in daylight savings or not (you can try `zone.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now)`)